# escape sequence javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I pass variable to other function in this condition ,
I'm inserting textarea through javascript with single quotes,
but when it gets called `myFunction(abc123)`, it looks like this,
the function suppose to be like this when it is called - `myFunction('abc123')`

so what should i do ?

```
myNum=123;
focusVar = "abc"+myNum;

$("#myDiv").append('<textarea onFocus="onFocusReportReply('+focusVar+')" onBlur="onBlurReportReply()" id="replyReportText'+data.activityId1+'">')
```

Comment: `focusVar = "'abc"+myNum+"'";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#myDiv").append('<textarea onFocus="onFocusReportReply(\''+focusVar+'\')" onBlur="onBlurReportReply()" id="replyReportText'+data.activityId1+'">')
```

Backslashes escape special characters, in this case string delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use *double quotes* or *escaped single quotes*.

```
var foo = 'onFocus=myFunc("' + focusVar + '") moar';
```

or

```
var foo = 'onFocus=myFunc(\'' + focusVar + '\') moar';
```

---

To escape special characters, you need a leading backslash. Examples are

```
\t (tabulator)
\n (line feed)
\\ (backslash)
```

Comment: He can't use double quotes because those delimit his attribute value.

Comment: @Asad: thats why my first example just uses *doublequotes* for the inner parameters. He doesn't need to quote the whole attribute

Comment: Perhaps it isn't imperative to  quote your attribute values, but it is good practice.

Comment: @Asad: I wouldn't know why it is "not good practice" to use an unquotet attribute value. W3C allows for all types, single-quoted, double-quoted and not-quoted.

Comment: Well for one, your HTML is instantly non XHTML, and some validators have trouble parsing just HTML if there are unquoted attributes. Another (more significant) disadvantage is that you can't have spaces in your attribute values.

Comment: However that is a whole different argument than saying it is "bad practice" in my mind. However, the author knows if there are spaces required or not, so its absolutely fine to go with non-quoted attribute values.

Comment: What I meant when I said it is "bad practice" is that doing the opposite has no significant disadvantages, and several foreseeable advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your string inside single quotes, like this:

```
myNum=123;
focusVar = "'abc"+myNum+"'";
```